# Compile mkclean on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: compiling

I'm struggling to compile [mkclean](https://www.matroska.org/downloads/mkclean.html) on Ubuntu 16.04.

I download the file and extract it but when I run `./configure` I get this:

```
./configure: 2: ./configure: %%BEGIN: not found
./configure: 3: ./configure: SCRIPT: not found
./configure: 4: ./configure: %%END: not found
make: *** corec/tools/coremake: No such file or directory.  Stop.
mv: cannot stat 'corec/tools/coremake/coremake': No such file or directory
./configure: 1: ./configure: corec/tools/coremake/system_output.sh: not found
Running ./coremake
./configure: 11: ./configure: ./coremake: not found
Now you can run make -C %(PROJECT_NAME) or gmake -C %(PROJECT_NAME)
```

Any help? I can only find old results and they don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkclean` now uses CMake:

```sh
tar xf mkclean-0.9.0.tar.bz2
cd mkclean-0.9.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

In older versions of `mkclean`, using autoconf, the `configure` script needs to be processed before it can be used. You should run

```
./mkclean/configure.compiled
```

from the parent directory instead, after converting its end-of-line characters (using `fromdos` from the `tofrodos` package):

```
fromdos mkclean/configure.compiled
```

The full build sequence, starting with the downloaded source code, is:

```
tar xf mkclean-0.8.10.tar.bz2
cd mkclean-0.8.10
fromdos mkclean/configure.compiled
./mkclean/configure.compiled
make -C mkclean
```

This gives me a `release/gcc_linux_x64/mkclean` binary.

Comment: I had to install package tofrodos for your 2nd command to work. I'm still getting the same error message after running your 2nd command and 1st

Comment: Running `./mkclean/configure.compiled` still produces errors?

Comment: now it worked. I still cant use mkclean from terminal, any tip in how to achieve that? Thanks so much by the way!

Comment: From the same directory, `./release/gcc_linux_x64/mkclean` works for me. `make -C mkclean install` (as root) would install the program in `/usr/local/bin`, so you’d be able to run it without specifying its path (if `/usr/local/bin` is on your `PATH`).

Comment: It seems that with the newest version this answer doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @Freedo see the update. The `ReadMe.txt` file also explains how to build...